# Pulling data from BigQuery, Chunking it to 100KB csv and store on the GCS bucket

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, data-science

I want pull 15GB (large) data from BigQuery table, chunk it to 150KB multiple files with wildcard naming format and store on them GCS bucket and then read each file and sent it to external API.

Currently I'm running the following code but the chunk size is by default 1GB. How should I proceed if I want each chunk to be of 150KB and the naming convention will be the wildcard way.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'buck_address'
project = "test-main-project"
dataset_id = "address_dataset"
table_id = "address"

destination_uri = "gs://{}/address-*.csv".format(bucket_name)
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    location="us-central1",
) 
extract_job.result() 

# print the exported path for confirmation
print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```